# Post() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'

Tags: django

How can I solve this error in my Django Python code?

> Post() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'

```
views.py     
    def post(request):
        if request.method=="POST":
            Image=request.FILES['image']
            caption=request.POST.get('ta','')
            userr=request.user
            post_obj=Post(user=userr,image=Image,caption=caption)
            print(userr,Image,caption,end='\n')

            post_obj.save()
            messages.success(request,"Succusfully sent your Post")
            return redirect('/user_homeview')
            return HttpResponse("successfully")
        else:
            # messages.error(request,"your  Post not succesfully sent! something went wrong!")
            return redirect('/user_homeview')
            return HttpResponse(" not successfully")



            return render(request,'userview/userhome.html')
    #Post() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'
    so how i solve this error
        def post(request):
            if request.method=="POST":
                Image=request.FILES['image']
                caption=request.POST.get('ta','')
                userr=request.user
                post_obj=Post(user=userr,image=Image,caption=caption)
                print(userr,Image,caption,end='\n')

                post_obj.save()

        models.py
        from django.db import models
        from django.contrib.auth.models import User
        # # Create your models here.
        from django.db import models

        # # # Create your models here.
        class Post(models.Model):
             userr = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
             image=models.FileField(upload_to='media/',blank=True)
             caption = models.CharField(max_length=200,default="")
             timeStamp=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,blank=True,null=True)
```

Comment: how i solve this error  views.py   {{{{              }}}}}}

Comment: you defined the field in your post model is `userr` but in your view you are using `Post(user=userr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo, in this line:

`post_obj=Post(user=userr,image=Image,caption=caption)` ; regarding your models.py, it should be `userr=userr`